# GET custom_fields.text.value from Stripe API in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: stripe-payments, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to make a get request to the Stripe API that gets a user based on the custom value that is entered by the customer. The query now returns all users but I want just 1 user. E.g. how would I get the user where the custom value is "Jacob". I tried some examples following the search query language as described in the Stripe API documentation but I can't figure it out. Do you have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

I tried a lot of queries but they all respond with a list of all the users. I tried for example the following:

[https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions?custom_fields.text.value:"Jacob"](https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions?custom_fields.text.value:%22Jacob%22)

https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions

The response is always with multiple users like this:

{
"object": "list",
"data": [
{
"id": "cs_test_a1s5jKQSuTRk5P3FfsHMQCUrDVBqxPLeinAKA9lvTtZsDMNRuGXlDRNdWN",
"object": "checkout.session",
"after_expiration": null,
"allow_promotion_codes": false,
"amount_subtotal": 500,
"amount_total": 500,
"automatic_tax": {
"enabled": true,
"status": "complete"
},
"billing_address_collection": "auto",
"cancel_url": "https://stripe.com",
"client_reference_id": null,
"consent": null,
"consent_collection": {
"promotions": "none",
"terms_of_service": "none"
},
"created": 1696582486,
"currency": "eur",
"currency_conversion": null,
"custom_fields": [
{
"dropdown": null,
"key": "deviceid",
"label": {
"custom": "Device ID",
"type": "custom"
},
"numeric": null,
"optional": false,
"text": {
"maximum_length": null,
"minimum_length": null,
"value": "Stijn"
},
"type": "text"
}
],
"custom_text": {
"shipping_address": null,
"submit": null,
"terms_of_service_acceptance": null
},
"customer": "cus_OlhDRNITdeHGlj",
"customer_creation": "if_required",
"customer_details": {
"address": {
"city": null,
"country": "NL",
"line1": null,
"line2": null,
"postal_code": null,
"state": null
},
"email": "mymail@gmail.com",
"name": "S. Surname",
"phone": null,
"tax_exempt": "none",
"tax_ids": []
},
"customer_email": null,
"expires_at": 1696668886,
"invoice": "in_1Ny9ouFb8QkNpja8gRjnp121",
"invoice_creation": null,
"livemode": false,
"locale": "auto",
"metadata": {},
"mode": "subscription",
"payment_intent": null,
"payment_link": "plink_1Ny8K4Fb8QkNpja8UHnkSH1t",
"payment_method_collection": "always",
"payment_method_configuration_details": null,
"payment_method_options": null,
"payment_method_types": [
"card"
],
"payment_status": "paid",
"phone_number_collection": {
"enabled": false
},
"recovered_from": null,
"setup_intent": null,
"shipping_address_collection": null,
"shipping_cost": null,
"shipping_details": null,
"shipping_options": [],
"status": "complete",
"submit_type": "auto",
"subscription": "sub_1Ny9ouFb8QkNpja8RhV7sv0i",
"success_url": "https://stripe.com",
"total_details": {
"amount_discount": 0,
"amount_shipping": 0,
"amount_tax": 0
},
"url": null
},
{
"id": "cs_test_a19WInedGT86yB3x0J09RVNoCTrYwVa6ue9otLUaaICIK0UVciVOkt8J1X",
"object": "checkout.session",
"after_expiration": null,
"allow_promotion_codes": false,
"amount_subtotal": 500,
"amount_total": 500,
"automatic_tax": {
"enabled": true,
"status": "complete"
},
"billing_address_collection": "auto",
"cancel_url": "https://stripe.com",
"client_reference_id": null,
"consent": null,
"consent_collection": {
"promotions": "none",
"terms_of_service": "none"
},
"created": 1696576812,
"currency": "eur",
"currency_conversion": null,
"custom_fields": [
{
"dropdown": null,
"key": "deviceid",
"label": {
"custom": "Device ID",
"type": "custom"
},
"numeric": null,
"optional": false,
"text": {
"maximum_length": null,
"minimum_length": null,
"value": "Jacob"
},
"type": "text"
}
],
"custom_text": {
"shipping_address": null,
"submit": null,
"terms_of_service_acceptance": null
},
"customer": "cus_OlfgQ8SHoECHPJ",
"customer_creation": "if_required",
"customer_details": {
"address": {
"city": null,
"country": "NL",
"line1": null,
"line2": null,
"postal_code": null,
"state": null
},
"email": "mymail@gmail.com",
"name": "myName",
"phone": null,
"tax_exempt": "none",
"tax_ids": []
},
"customer_email": null,
"expires_at": 1696663212,
"invoice": "in_1Ny8KyFb8QkNpja8w1o1hiKC",
"invoice_creation": null,
"livemode": false,
"locale": "en",
"metadata": {},
"mode": "subscription",
"payment_intent": null,
"payment_link": "plink_1Ny8K4Fb8QkNpja8UHnkSH1t",
"payment_method_collection": "always",
"payment_method_configuration_details": null,
"payment_method_options": null,
"payment_method_types": [
"card"
],
"payment_status": "paid",
"phone_number_collection": {
"enabled": false
},
"recovered_from": null,
"setup_intent": null,
"shipping_address_collection": null,
"shipping_cost": null,
"shipping_details": null,
"shipping_options": [],
"status": "complete",
"submit_type": "auto",
"subscription": "sub_1Ny8KyFb8QkNpja8DqEFdCWt",
"success_url": "https://stripe.com",
"total_details": {
"amount_discount": 0,
"amount_shipping": 0,
"amount_tax": 0
},
"url": null
}
],
"has_more": false,
"url": "/v1/checkout/sessions"
}

Comment: There is no `search()` method for Checkout sessions yet, just a `list()` method. This `list()` method only supports a few query parameters you can use to filter the list :
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list The custom_field values is not one of them, which would mean that you should filter out the results of your list, rather than the list itself.

Comment: As noted above, there's no way to filter sessions by `custom_fields` values via the API currently. You'd need to handle this filtering in your own code. Can you elaborate further on your use case as there may be a better way to persist this data.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little workaround for my problem. I now get the Stripe user
ID whenever a charge is added and save the ID  on Azure. Then in the Logic App I check which ID corresponds with the user ID and perform the get request for the checkout list based on this ID. It is not that elegant perhaps (and maybe there is a better answer) but this works fine for now.